# Format String Array from a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm trying to test my methods, but I am having trouble with the logAsArray. When I run it the output comes back looking like machine code. I think I have to use a toString() but I can't figure out where to place it...
I am also getting a null pointer exception when testing smallest. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
    public class hw {
public static void main(String[] args){
String name = null;
LinkedStringLog myInstance =  new LinkedStringLog(name);
myInstance.insert("Bob");
myInstance.insert("Carl");
myInstance.insert("Ace");
myInstance.insert("Steve");
myInstance.insert("Mike");
myInstance.size();
int i = (myInstance.size());
while ( i != 0) {
System.out.println(myInstance.name);
System.out.println(myInstance.size());
System.out.println(myInstance.isEmpty());
System.out.println(myInstance.howMany(""));
System.out.println(myInstance.uniqInsert(""));
myInstance.smallest());
System.out.println(myInstance.logAsArray());
i--;    }}
```

}

```
    public String[] logAsArray(){
  String values[] = new String [size()];
    LLStringNode node;
    node = log;
    int i = 0;
      while (node != null){
      values[i] = node.getInfo();
      node = node.getLink();
      i++;
      }
      return values;  }



    public String smallest(){
LLStringNode node;
LLStringNode node2;
LLStringNode node3 = log;
node = log;
node2 = log;
String smallString = "A";
boolean notNull = (node != null);
boolean notNull2 = (node2 != null);
while (notNull && notNull2){               
 System.out.println(node.getInfo() + " " + node2.getInfo());
 if (node.getInfo().compareTo(node2.getInfo()) <= 0) // null pointer exception
 {
 node3 = node;
 node2 = node2.getLink();
 smallString = node3.getInfo();
 }
 else if (notNull && notNull2)
 {
 node3 = node2;
node = node.getLink();
smallString = node3.getInfo();
      }
 smallString = node3.getInfo();
 }      
return smallString;}



      public int size()
      // Returns the number of Strings in this StringLog.
      {
        int count = 0;
        LLStringNode node;
        node = log;
        while (node != null)
        {
          count++;
          node = node.getLink();
         }
        return count;  }
```

Comment: Several places in your code are confusing.  For instance, where is the `size()` method defined which you use in this line: `String values[] = new String [size()];` With regard to seeing "machine code" from `logAsArray()`, the most likely explanation for this is that you are trying to print a String array.  Try this instead: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myInstance.logAsArray()));`

Comment: What is `log`? I can't find it? Also what does `size()` return. Usually when asking for help you should take the time to format your question.

Comment: Log is a reference to the first node of the linked list that holds the strings. I was unsure of how much I needed to include for it to make sense, but at the same time I didn't want to post everything. I forgot to include the size method, but it returns an int.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to iterate through the log and print each specific String.

```
for (String s : whateverLog)
    System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: Or you could just use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(whateverLog))`